# How to insert as much values into another table as it's definied in a specific colum from other table

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have two tables, Movements and sales

**Movements** (example)

```
clock_model| piece_ref| original_stock |
-----------+----------+-----------------
R0000000000| 0000ZZZ  |       5        |
```

**Sales** (I just show you the structure)

```
id_sale (autoincrement numeric value)
piece_ref
pieces_to_sent 
type_of_sale
customer
lastupdate_date
lastupdate_by
```

I would like to know which query should be the right one to insert as many piece_ref into sales table as its result would be something like this from the example above:

**Sales**

```
id_sale| piece_ref|  pieces_to_sent | type_of_sale | customer | lastupdate_date
-------+----------+-----------------+--------------+----------+-----------------
1      | 0000ZZZ  |       0         |  "none"      | "no one" |      NOW()
2      | 0000ZZZ  |       0         |  "none"      | "no one" |      NOW()
3      | 0000ZZZ  |       0         |  "none"      | "no one" |      NOW()
4      | 0000ZZZ  |       0         |  "none"      | "no one" |      NOW()
5      | 0000ZZZ  |       0         |  "none"      | "no one" |      NOW()
```

I think that the postgresql query would be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `Sales` (`piece_ref`, `pieces_to_sent `, 
`type_of_sale`, `customer`,`lastupdate_date`)

SELECT `Movements`.`piece_ref`, 0, "", "", NOW(), "admin"  
FROM   `Movements`, generate_series(1, `Movements`.original_stock) AS rn
```

But as you know generate_series function doesn't exists in MySQL. Could you please provide me some help on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to do this?

Comment: I'm working on Jquery DataTables using MySQL, and I'm creating a second datatable that get this kind of relationship, as Datatables doesn't accept empty table as Datasource, I have to initialize this table first with anything. I know this is not elegant... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an auxiliary table with numbers from 1 to N 
(where N is maximum number of pieces you will ever want to insert).
For example:

```
CREATE TABLE numbers( x int primary key auto_increment );

INSERT INTO numbers
SELECT null FROM information_schema.columns
LIMIT 100;
```

This table can be used in the following query to generate necessary records:

```
SELECT '0000ZZZ', 0,'none','no one',NOW()
FROM movements m
JOIN numbers n
ON n.x <= m.original_stock
```

and then insert them into the table:

```
INSERT INTO sales( piece_ref, pieces_to_sent, type_of_sale, 
                   customer, lastupdate_date )
SELECT '0000ZZZ', 0,'none','no one',NOW()
FROM movements m
JOIN numbers n
ON n.x <= m.original_stock
```

Demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc299/1

---

EDIT.
The above query is for MySql, in PostGreSql the table with numbers is not required, use `generate_series` function instead:

```
INSERT INTO sales( piece_ref, pieces_to_sent, type_of_sale, customer, lastupdate_date )
select '0000ZZZ', 0,'none','no one',NOW()
from generate_series(1,(SELECT max(original_stock) FROM movements) ) x
join movements m
on x <= m.original_stock;
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/3720c/1

Comment: It was just related not to PostGreSQL, but to MySQL, but that the INSERT_INTO and the creation of the numbers table did the trick, I'll drop numbers table after first INSERT execution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Below code is in reference to mysql.

```
$mydata = mysql_query("SELECT `piece_ref`,`original_stock` FROM `Movements`");
if(mysql_row_nums($mydata)>0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mydata)){
         for($i=0;$i<(int)$row['original_stock'];$i++){
             mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Sales` (`piece_ref`, `pieces_to_sent `, `type_of_sale`, `customer`,`lastupdate_date`) values('".$row['piece_ref']."',0,'','','".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."')");
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question was related just to SQL, but I have to admit that this is the kind of php I'll use on my addition of movements functionality. I appreciate it, thank you!